# google app engine with python 500 error keeps coming

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I have created a google app engine application called Ascii Art at this link http://ascii-chan-1018.appspot.com/ but for some reason sometimes when you post something it gives you this error code on the screen 
"500 Internal Server Error The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation." Sometimes it works and sometimes it gives you this error code. I'm not sure if its my source code or if its an error on google's servers.

```
import os     
import re
import sys
import urllib2
import random
import logging
from xml.dom import minidom
from string import letters
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

art_key = db.Key.from_path('ASCIIChan', 'arts')

def console(s):
        sys.stderr.write('%s\n' % s)

IP_URL = "http://api.hostip.info/?ip="
def get_coords(ip):
        ip = "17.173.254.223"
        url = IP_URL + ip
        content = None
        try:
                content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        except URLError:
                return

        if content:
                d = minidom.parseString(content)
                coords = d.getElementsByTagName("gml:coordinates")
                if coords and coords[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue:
                        lon, lat = coords[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.split(',')
                        return db.GeoPt(lat, lon)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def write(self, *a, **kw):
                self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

        def render_str(self, template, **params):
                t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
                return t.render(params)

        def render(self, template, **kw):
                self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

GMAPS_URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=380x263&sensor=false&"
def gmap_img(points):
        markers = '&'.join('markers=%s,%s' % (p.lat, p.lon) for p in points)
        return GMAPS_URL + markers

class Art(db.Model):
        title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
        art = db.TextProperty(required = True)
        created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
        coords = db.GeoPtProperty( )

def top_arts(update = False):
        key = 'top'
        arts = memcache.get(key)
        if arts is None or update:
                logging.error("DB QUERY")
                arts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                        "FROM Art "
                                        "WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 "
                                        "ORDER BY created DESC "
                                        "LIMIT 10",
                                        art_key)
                arts = list(arts)
                memcache.set(key, arts)
        return arts

class MainPage(Handler):
        def render_front(self, title="", art="", error=""):
                arts = top_arts()

                img_url = None
                points = filter(None, (a.coords for a in arts))
                if points:
                        img_url = gmap_img(points)

                #display the image URL
                self.render("Ascii.html", title = title, art = art, error = error, arts = arts, img_url = img_url)

        def get(self):
                self.render_front()

        def post(self):
                title = self.request.get("title")
                art = self.request.get("art")

                if title and art:
                        p = Art(parent=art_key, title = title, art = art)
                        #lookup the user's coordinates from their IP
                        coords = get_coords(self.request.remote_addr)
                        #if we have coordinates, add them to the art
                        if coords:
                                p.coords = coords
                        p.put()
                        #rerun the query and update the cache
                        top_arts(True)

                        self.redirect("/")
                else:
                        error = "Invalid, are you sure you entered a title and art work?"
                        self.render_front(error = error, title = title, art =art)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])
```

Comment: Post some of the code.

Comment: Ok here is the code it also was suppose to use this google maps API but I removed it and still have some of the code

Comment: I don't really know an answer to this, but have you tried taking things apart and test as you go, it will lead to the exact problem...

Comment: Yea Im trying that now and it wasn't occuring when I tested it on my own desktop but perhaps it could be my code.

Comment: Thanks for trying however!

Comment: nice, you should answer your question here for anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure if you can consider it solving the problem but I just removed the google maps code that was left over. It kept complaining about the line except URLError, so after I removed the maps code it worked fine, and my initial plan was to remove it anyways.